# Laravel eloquent linking through models to display data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is a beginner question. I have an Area model, and a Subarea model. An Area has many Subareas, and a Subarea belongs to an Area. I am trying to link through the models (unsure of the correct terminology) and find all of the subareas for one area.

These are my models.

```
class Area extends Model
{
    public function subarea()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subarea::class);
    }
}

class Subarea extends Model
{
    public function area() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class);
    }
}
```

In a controller, I am doing,

```
public function index()
{
    $areas = Area::all();

    return view('area.area', compact('areas'));
}
```

In a view,

```
@foreach($areas->subareas as $subarea)
    {{ $subarea->subarea_name }}
@endforeach
```

In rails I am able to do the following, and it works,

```
<% areas.subareas.each do |subarea| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= subarea.subarea_name %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Is anyone able to point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Also, as a bonus question. Is there a better place to get all of the areas and pass it to the view? I have the query in the model, which I know is bad practice. Does anyone know where I should put it instead?

Thanks!

**Update**

This is the error I am getting

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$subarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the loop to:

```
@foreach($areas as $area)
    //subarea singular (the relation name)
    @foreach($area->subarea as $subarea)
        {{ $subarea->subarea_name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

For better performance, you must eager load the `subareas`:

```
$areas = Area::with('subarea')->get();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I changed as you suggested, and am getting the above error.

Comment: Did you change the request too ? `$areas = Area::with('subarea')->get();`

Comment: Not weird at all :D `$areas` is a collection you must loop through its elements ! check the Updated code :D

Comment: Ahhh, I see the mistake, thank you! I really appreciate your help! =)

Comment: U'r welcome :D don't forget  to add `with('subarea')` to eager load the models ! Else your code will perform a db request in each iteration  (N+1 problem)